# Change integer to float column table Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I need to change `t.integer :mark_up` to a `float` How can I do this? I have tried in my terminal `rails g migration change_column(:stakes, :mark_up, :float)` by keep getting a `syntax error near unexpected token ('`

Answer (score 27):

In your terminal:

```
rails generate migration ChangeMarkUpToFloat
```

and in the file that is created: `db/migrate/2015xxxxxxxxxx/change_mark_up_to_float.rb`

edit it to:

```
class ChangeMarkUpToFloat < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_column :stakes, :mark_up, :float
  end
end
```

and then back in your terminal:

```
rake db:migrate
```

Comment: This is ok when the app is not in production. When the app is in production, I would recommend following engineyard's guide on [zero downtime deployment](https://blog.engineyard.com/2011/zero-downtime-deploys-with-migrations)

Comment: Be careful with using the `change` method when a migration really isn't reversible. If you ran `rake db:migrate:down`, how would it know what type to convert to? Consider defining `up` and `down` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use rails code (`change_column`) in your terminal.

What you need to do is first create the migration: `rails generate migration ChangeMarkUpType` and then put your rails code in the file that was created.

You can read more about migrations [here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#creating-a-migration)

Comment: ok i did that and defined change as change_column :stake, :mark_up, :float but my schema still shows that :mark_up is an integer

Comment: did you run rake db:migrate?

Comment: @NeilMurphy Did you see the migration run? Can you update your question with the code in the migration file?